# JSON parse error with ajax response string

Tags: javascript, json

I have been working on this issue and i have searched for the solution in the web and stackoverflow, but I cant get whats the error exactly.

this is the json string coming from the server through the ajax call.

```
{root:{name: "root",description: "root description",checked: false,1:{name: "item1",description: "item1 description",checked: true,1.1:{name: "item1.1",description: "item1.1 description",checked: true}}, 2:{name: "item2",description: "item2 description",checked: true}}}
```

using the below code i am getting the string after `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200`

```
var aData;
        try{
        aData =JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        catch(err){
        alert(err);
        }
```

it shows the error like

```
Json.parse expected property name or '}'
```

but if use eval() function it works fine

```
var aData;
        try{
        aData =eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
        }
        catch(err){
        alert(err);
        }
```

please exaplin what is the error here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have checked the string in json viewer and its worked fine.
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/">
[image: JSON view]

Comment: Well, that's not valid JSON. Keys must be in double quotes. See http://json.org/ and http://jsonlint.com/. It's a valid JS object literal though, that's why `eval` works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax JSON Parse Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428329/ajax-json-parse-error)

Comment: I'm guessing you can't call your items 1, 2, etc. as these aren't valid variable names in javascript.

Comment: @Lee: Thy might not be valid variables names, but they are valid object property names.

Comment: The tool you are evaluating the JSON is in does not seem to distinguish between actual JSON and object literals. The JSON is not valid, that's why `JSON.parse` does not work. Try http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because that's invalid JSON, you cannot use numbers as key names. So, you can either skip the numbers or put them in quotes so that they are "strings".

Validator output and fixed JSON are below:

Fixed JSON:

```
{
   "root":{
      "name":"root",
      "description":"root description",
      "checked":false,
      "1":{
         "name":"item1",
         "description":"item1 description",
         "checked":true,
         "1.1":{
            "name":"item1.1",
            "description":"item1.1 description",
            "checked":true
         }
      },
      "2":{
         "name":"item2",
         "description":"item2 description",
         "checked":true
      }
   }
}
```

Validator output:

```
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 2]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 5]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 9]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 13]
Error:Expecting string, not number.[Code 8, Structure 17]
Error:Expecting comma or }, not colon.[Code 13, Structure 18]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 20]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 24]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 28]
Error:Expecting string, not number.[Code 8, Structure 32]
Error:Expecting comma or }, not colon.[Code 13, Structure 33]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 35]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 39]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 43]
Error:Expecting string, not number.[Code 8, Structure 49]
Error:Expecting comma or }, not colon.[Code 13, Structure 50]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 52]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 56]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 60]
```